# Django complex filter and order

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have 4 model like this

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_lowest_price(self, mm_date):
        '''This method returns lowest product price on a site at a particular date'''

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Price(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Here every have many category, every category have many product. Now product price can change every day so price model will hold the product price and date.

My problem is I want list of site filter by price range. This price range will depends on the get_lowest_price method and can be sort Min to Max and Max to Min. Already I've used lambda expression to do that but I think it's not appropriate

```
sorted(Site.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.get_lowest_price(the_date))
```

Also I can get all site within a price range by running a loop but this is also not a good idea. Please help my someone to do the query in right manner.

If you still need more clear view of the question please see the first comment from "Ishtiaque Khan", his assumption is 100% right.

*In these models writing frequency is low and reading frequency is high.

Comment: Your business logic is not clear. It seems you are trying to find a list of unique sites sorted by V, where V is the minimum price of all the products in that site for a given date. If this is the business logic then the current approach is not optimal. If your date range is within a few years and if your database is a static one, or has very infrequent data entries, an eager evaluation of the lowest V for each date on each new entry seems to be a good idea. So pre-caculation/eager calculation might the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Using query**
If you just wanna query using a specific date. Here is how:

```py
q = Site.objects.filter(category__product__price__date=mm_date) \
        .annotate(min_price=Min('category__product__price__price')) \
        .filter(min_price__gte=min_price, min_price__lte=max_price)
```

It will return a list of Site with lowest price on `mm_date` fall within range of `min_price` - `max_price`. You can also query for multiple date using query like so:

```py
q = Site.objects.values('name', 'category__product__price__date') \
        .annotate(min_price=Min('category__product__price__price')) \
        .filter(min_price__gte=min_price, min_price__lte=max_price)
```

**2. Eager/pre-calculation**, you can use `post_save` signal. Since the write frequency is low this will not be expensive

- Create another **Table** to hold lowest prices per date. Like this:

```py
    class LowestPrice(models.Model):
        date = models.DateField()
        site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
        lowest_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

- Use `post_save` signal to calculate and update this every time there. Sample code (not tested)

```py
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.dispatch import receiver

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Price)
    def update_price(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        cur_price = LowestPrice.objects.filter(site=instance.product.category.site, date=instance.date).first()
        if not cur_price:
            new_price = LowestPrice()
            new_price.site = instance.product.category.site
            new_price.date = instance.date
        else:
            new_price = cur_price
        # update price only if needed
        if instance.price<new_price.lowest_price:
            new_price.lowest_price = instance.price
            new_price.save()
```

- Then just query directly from this table when needed:

```py
    LowestPrice.objects.filter(date=mm_date, lowest_price__gte=min_price, lowest_price__lte=max_price)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Site.objects.annotate(
    price_min=Min('categories__products__prices__price')
).filter(
    categories__products__prices__date=the_date,
).distinct().order_by('price_min')   # prefix '-' for descending order
```

For this to work, you need to modify the models by adding a `related_name` attribute to the ForeignKey fields.

Like this -

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # rest of the fields
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='categories')
```

Similary, for Product and Price models, add `related_name` as `products` and `prices` in the ForeignKey fields.

**Explanation**:

Starting with `related_name`, it describes the reverse relation from one model to another.
After the reverse relationship is setup, you can use them to inner join the tables.
You can use the reverse relationships to get the price of a product of a category on a site and `annotate` the min price, filtered by `the_date`. I have used the annotated value to order by min price of the product, in ascending order. You can use '-' as a prefix character to do in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with django queryset operations

```
Price.objects.all().order_by('price') #add [0] for only the first object
```

or

```
Price.objects.all().order_by('-price') #add [0] for only the first object
```

or

```
Price.objects.filter(date= ... ).order_by('price') #add [0] for only the first object
```

or

```
Price.objects.filter(date= ... ).order_by('-price') #add [0] for only the first object
```

or

```
Price.objects.filter(date= ... , price__gte=lower_limit, price__lte=upper_limit ).order_by('price') #add [0] for only the first object
```

or

```
Price.objects.filter(date= ... , price__gte=lower_limit, price__lte=upper_limit ).order_by('-price') #add [0] for only the first object
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. I do not want the price list I want the site list

Comment: Then your lamda expression seems to be right - no need to change it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this ORM query could do the job ...

```
from django.db.models import Min

sites = Site.objects.annotate(price_min= Min('category__product__price'))
            .filter(category__product__price=mm_date).unique().order_by('price_min')
```

or /and for reversing the order :

```
sites = Site.objects.annotate(price_min= Min('category__product__price'))
            .filter(category__product__price=mm_date).unique().order_by('-price_min')
```